# Tmux - Creating new sessions display some list of errors

Tags: tmux

How can i fix this anyone please? 
When i create a new session `tmux new -s sample_session` The list of errors always appeared.

- home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:3: unknown command: bell-action
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:4: unknown command: bell-on-alert
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:5: unknown command: default-command
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:6: unknown command: default-shell
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:7: unknown command: default-terminal
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:8: unknown command: destroy-unattached
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:9: unknown command: detach-on-destroy
- /home/glennfield/.tmux.conf:10: unknown command: display-panes-active-- colour

  *Here's my tmux.conf*

assume-paste-time 1
base-index 0
bell-action any
bell-on-alert off
default-command ""
default-shell "/bin/bash"
default-terminal "screen"
destroy-unattached off
detach-on-destroy on
display-panes-active-colour red
display-panes-colour blue
display-panes-time 1000
display-time 750
history-limit 2000
lock-after-time 0
lock-command "lock -np"
lock-server on
message-command-style fg=yellow,bg=black
message-style fg=black,bg=yellow
mouse-resize-pane off
mouse-select-pane off
mouse-select-window off
mouse-utf8 on
prefix C-b
prefix2 none
renumber-windows off
repeat-time 500
set-remain-on-exit off
set-titles off
set-titles-string "#S:#I:#W - "#T""
status on
status-interval 15
status-justify left
status-keys vi
status-left "[#S] "
status-left-length 10
status-left-style default
status-position bottom
status-right " "#{=21:pane_title}" %H:%M %d-%b-%y"
status-right-length 40
status-right-style default
status-style fg=black,bg=green
status-utf8 on
update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID
SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
visual-activity off
visual-bell off
visual-silence off
word-separators " -_@"

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your tmux.conf
The commands you use don't exist or are uncomplete

Ex : you should use display-panes-colour instead display-panes-active-- colour
full command should be something like :
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour colour33